# Why my deep learning model is not making use of GPU but working in CPU?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu, cpu-usage

Why my deep learning model is not making use of GPU but working in CPU?

Screenshot of laptop performance:
[image: Screenshot of laptop performance]

Comment: Add little more information like which framework you are using and it will be helpful if you add sample code too.

Comment: That's a very difficult question to answer. It looks like you're using Tensorflow on Windows. Do you have the CUDA SDK installed? Do you have the proper drivers? Do you have the correct tensorflow package installed?

Comment: I am using keras framework for image classification @Mukul

Answer (score 2):

GPU is fit for training the deep learning systems in a long run for very large datasets. CPU can train a deep learning model quite slowly. GPU accelerates the training of the model. Hence, GPU is a better choice to train the Deep Learning Model efficiently and effectively.

GPUs are optimized for training artificial intelligence and deep learning models as they can process multiple computations simultaneously.

Advantages of using a GPU for deep learning:
*Each GPU has a large number of cores, allowing for better computation of multiple parallel processes.

*Deep learning computations need to handle large amounts of data, making the high memory bandwidth in GPUs (which can run at up to 750 GB/s vs only 50 GB/s offered by traditional CPUs) better suited to a deep learning machine.

Please go through the below article,Hope it will help you,

https://towardsdatascience.com/tensorflow-gpu-installation-made-easy-use-conda-instead-of-pip-52e5249374bc